# Is there a way to have the django admin model list link to the last page of resutls?

Tags: django, admin

We have these moderately large and constantly growing tables and the most interesting stuff is always the most recent. Currently we have them ordered by creation time, so the interesting stuff is at the end. This requires 2 clicks when navigating, one to select the model and another select the last page.

I could of course change the order so the most recent stuff is at the front, but then the content of the pages would be continually changing as new stuff is pushed on the front, making exploration of the history harder.

So I was wondering if there was a way to have it go straight to the last page?

Comment: If the most interesting stuff is at the end, simply change the ordering as you've mentioned and drop the pagination at all in favor of filtering and infinite-scroll.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty peculiar request, but you could redirect the admin view if there is no `page` parameter in the URL (i.e. you are on the frontpage).

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        if not request.GET.get("p", False):
            return redirect("%s?p=%s" % (
                reverse("admin:my_app__model__changeview"), 
                self.paginator.page_range[-1])
        super(MyAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

an alternative is to inject a `p` URL paremeter into the request before passing control over to the parent `changelist_view` method (but this requires copying the request). **Edit**: [Wouter's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13821697/396300) is actually nice and simple

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do here, but I've having problems getting it going, specifically "self.paginator.page_range[-1]" is producing "'property' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the `change_list` template (the `pagination` block) to show `{{page.last}}`

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggesting here, surely by the time it gets to the template it has already decided what page it is going to display and loaded the associated data